# Thymeleaf 3 URL resolving not working with Spring Boot 4 + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

After having configured Thymeleaf 3 in Spring Boot 4 using the Gradle configuration

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.3.RELEASE')
```

and

```
ext['thymeleaf.version'] = '3.0.3.RELEASE'
ext['thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version'] = '2.1.2'
```

URL resolvers do not properly resolve the URLs in Thymeleaf views:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css" data-th-href="@{~/css/login.css}">
```

simply becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
```

I have done some debugging and first of all, during a request I noticed that [SaveToSessionResponseWrapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f221920a1990f458b26b185c8fbe5b3623dbd8c1/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java#L302) (sub of [SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorWrapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f221920a1990f458b26b185c8fbe5b3623dbd8c1/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java)) gets initialized like this:

```
public SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response,
        boolean disableUrlRewriting) {
    super(response);
    this.disableUrlRewriting = disableUrlRewriting;
}
```

The arguments passed are a [FireWalledResponse](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f221920a1990f458b26b185c8fbe5b3623dbd8c1/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/FirewalledResponse.java) and `false`. The latter results in the following method completely disabling the forwarding of URLs:

```
@Override
public final String encodeURL(String url) {
    if (this.disableUrlRewriting) {
        return url;
    }
    return super.encodeURL(url);
}
```

Now, if I put a breakpoint in the constructor and force `disableUrlRewriting` to be `true`, it eventually executes [HttpServletResponseImpl.isEncodeable](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/bcb177c2538dbd8023d893056c80ac24cfd3aafd/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/spec/HttpServletResponseImpl.java#L675) which then fails here:

```
    } else if(hreq.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()) {
        return false;
```

At this point I'm not sure what is wrong. I'm unable to find anyone with this error and it works with neither `starter-tomcat` nor `starter-undertow` but I haven't done as thorough debugging in Tomcat yet.

Comment: What did you expect it resolve to?

Comment: @holmis83 a context-relative URL

Answer (score 1):

`@{~/css/login.css}` is a *server-relative* URL in Thymeleaf.

If you want a *context-relative* URL, omit the tilde (~) character:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css" data-th-href="@{/css/login.css}">
```

See [Standard URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) article for details.

Comment: If I use that, it'll still translate to `/css/login.css`. The same thing happens, no matter what URL I try.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css" th:href="@{/css/login.css}">
```

Without **data-th-href**

Comment: The same issue with that one, it simply fails to resolve. I don't even understand why `disableUrlRewriting` gets set to true.